I get the error “The requested security protocol is not supported” even though tls is turned on
I am working on a soap webservice application written with .net 3.5 framework. An external service we use has changed and I updated it, but even though I opened everything related to TLS on a windows 2012 R2 machine, I get The requested security protocol is not supported” error.

I created client server key for TLS 1.2 and 1.1 via registry editor and entered their values

SchUseStrongCrypto and SystemDefaultTlsVersions values were assigned as 1. both under wow6432Node and flat microsoft (although I selected v2 from the application pool for the .net 3.5 framework, I set it in v4 just in case)

I turned on TLS 1.0 1.1 1.1 1.2 over internet protocol

I made my additions on the code
public const SslProtocols _Tls12 = (SslProtocols)0x00000C00; 
public const SecurityProtocolType Tls12 = (SecurityProtocolType)_Tls12;  
//The following part is in the function I use
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Tls12;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
          {
              return true;
          };

works fine on other windows server 2016 machines I installed . What am I missing?



The SSL Protocol is not enough, you also need compatible Cipher Suites, which are most probably not present in that version of Windows Server. You may need to use a third-party stack, as OpenSSL, which comes with its own Cipher Suites -- Auto-validating the Server Certificate should only be done with well-trusted (possibly just internal) services. TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 should be disabled -- Use Wireshark or similar protocol analyzers / proxies to check the TLS transaction, to determine where it fails
